# Login in SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a class which extends `SwingWorker<Void, Void>`. In it's background thread I was supposed to do login, if successful changing layout and adding new panels to frame. So Swing worker do following 3 tasks:

1. Login
2. Change layout
3. Add/remove panels.

So I wrote this function in doInBackground() method. But what happens here is this 3 methods are always executed, no matter login is successful or not. I want to stop executing worker if login fails. I tried cancel() method but it did not worked. How can I do this in proper way? *What could be the proper way to do login task in SwingWorker?*

Comment: Using `return;` if you want to jump out of a method (as for any other void method)

Comment: You could also check whether the login was successful (or if the login happend before already) and only then execute steps 2 and 3.

Comment: @Thomas you mean returning true/false from login method and putting a if condition before executing 2 & 3 step?

Comment: Yes, that might be a possibility, especially if the login method would also check if the user's already logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second and third steps must NOT be done in the `doInBackground()` method, since they use Swing components and must thus be done in the event dispatch thread. They must be done in the `done()` method, if the login was successful.

So your SwingWorker should rather be a `SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>`. The `doInBackground()` method should return true if the login was successful, and false if not:

```
SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> loginWorker = new SwingWorker<Boolean, Void>() {
    protected Boolean doInBackground() {
        return login();
    }

    protected void done() {
        try {
            boolean loginSuccessful = get();
            if (loginSuccessful) {
                updateGUI();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            displayErrorMessage(e);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can I do same thing, I mean get() method, outside of this class from where I called execute()? Cause the updateGui method is time consuming, I also have to connect to server to get the details to be shown.

Comment: Using get after execute hangs UI so it seems like I can not use it. What else I can do? What I exactly want is I have associated a progress bar with this task so it should progress according to the steps completed. If I do all updateGUI in done method it doesn't run properly, I can't see all values form server on UI.

Answer (score 0):

As Robin said, use return.  In fact, step 1 should be done in a background thread while steps 2 and 3 in the event dispatch thread.  So

```
protected Void doInBackground() {
    boolean success = login();
    this.setSuccess(success); // so that other thread knows whether you logged in
}

protected void done() {
    if (this.getSuccess()) {
//Change layout
//Add/remove panels.
    }
}
```